# IOException Stream Closed on Gif

Tags: java, swing, gif, ioexception

I'm trying to display a Gif on a simple JFrame. I created the "LoadingGif" class, but  I got this error message `java.io.IOException : Stream closed` a second after the Gif appeared, then it stops.

I call this class with `LoadingGif.getInstance.runUI()` and the source code of the class is :

```
public class LoadingGif {

    private static LoadingGif instance = null;

    private JFrame f;
    private JLabel label;
    private URL url;
    private ImageIcon imageIcon;

    private LoadingGif()
    {
         url = TraceaReq.class.getResource("/load.gif");
         imageIcon = new ImageIcon(url);
         label = new JLabel(imageIcon);
    }

    public void runUI()
    {
         f = new JFrame(RQTFGenDOORS.VERSION+" - Loading...");
         f.getContentPane().add(label);
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         f.pack();
         f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         f.setResizable(false);
         f.setVisible(true);
         f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }

    public void stopLoading(){
        if(f.isDisplayable())
        {
            f.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static LoadingGif getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new LoadingGif();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why I got this stream closed ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How are you using/calling this class?

Comment: `imageIcon = new ImageIcon(url); label = new JLabel(imageIcon);` The label/icon will load the image asynchronously (other things can happen while it is loading), while this code `if(f.isDisplayable()) { f.dispose();` will cause the JVM to stop loading the image as soon as the frame is displayable. I suspect that is the problem. 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: This class is a singleton. I call this class at the very beginning of my main() by using `LoadingGif.getInstance.runUI()`, then at the very end I call `LoadingGif.getInstance.stopLoading()`

The thing is the image is well loaded, and the gif is animated for maybe 0.5s, then I got the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to simplify your sample code firstly. For example, I've just used hard-coded path to the GIF file (it's hard-coded for now to ensure that everything is OK with image location and there is not any issues with classpath, etc). Also I've used constructor of `LoadingGif` class instead of singleton factory.

My sample code looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class LoadingGif {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private ImageIcon imageIcon;

    private LoadingGif() {
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon("/home/me/Temp/loading-gif/src/animated-penguin-gif-5.gif");
        label = new JLabel(imageIcon);
    }

    public void runUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("MyGif - Loading...");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LoadingGif loadingGif = new LoadingGif();
        loadingGif.runUI();
    }   
}
```

And the [GIF](http://bestanimations.com/Animals/Birds/Penguins/animated-penguin-gif-5.gif) is animated and displayed without any errors.

In my case GIF file is not huge. May be in your case it's very big and takes some time to load, as already **@Andrew Thompson** said. Anyway, you can check whether the image is loaded with aid of `javax.swing.ImageIcon#getImageLoadStatus` method and then check the returned flag. For `java.awt.MediaTracker#COMPLETE` Javadoc says:

```
/**
 * Flag indicating that the downloading of media was completed
 * successfully.
 * @see         java.awt.MediaTracker#statusAll
 * @see         java.awt.MediaTracker#statusID
 */
public static final int COMPLETE = 8;
```